# Writing redirecting URL in htaccess in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

My current Url is

```
http://localhost/removalcenter/landing-page/?from=Algeria&to=Afghanistan&submit=Submit
```

I want to redirect to this current URL when the user enters URL
`http://localhost/removalcenter/removals-from-Algeria-to-Afghanistan`
from and to are querystring variables
My htaccess code is..

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /removalscenter/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /removalscenter/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Please provide me with the rule for this redirect.

Comment: Please don't use the htaccess for this. Take a look into https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule and https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag

Comment: You should not use .htaccess for that.

Comment: @Ranker Can you provide me with the code for this change.. As i am a newbie to this.

Comment: @cgee Can you provide me with the code for this change.. As i am a newbie to this

Comment: For that I need more information. Is landing-page a wordpress page?

Comment: @cgee Yes.. landing-page is a wordpress page and it is using a custom template.. in this template i have embedded the form.
You can check the functionality here http://zserver.in/P178wordpress/..

Answer (score 1):

You have to put this code into your functions.php

I didn't test it! It is only an example because you asked about some code.

After that YOU HAVE TO go to wordpress settings -> permalink and only save the settings. If you don't to that you will get a 404 error.

Read the information of wordpress codex:

> IMPORTANT: Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules
>   database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens,
>   Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any
>   changes.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^removalcenter/landing-page/removals-from-Algeria-to-Afghanistan/?', '/removalcenter/landing-page/?from=Algeria&to=Afghanistan&submit=Submit', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Comment: from and to are query string variables.. what to do for these??

Comment: He meant that Algeria and Afghanistan are variables that can change with each request.

Comment: Than he have to take a look into rewrite tags from wordpress. https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag